# Angular: Move a component's host element

Tags: angular

I've been writing Angular for a long time, and I have a possible use for something I've never needed before! But I don't know if it's safe.

Is it OK to move the native DOM element of a component around after it has been created? Not via `ViewRef` or things like that, but the raw DOM element. I tried it, and so far it seems to work. [Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brmaio?file=src/app/app.component.ts) that moves a component's host element in the DOM, and input bindings still work.

So, it seems to be OK at a glance, but is this *supposed* to work (and will continue working in future version of Angular) or does it *happen* to work (and may break without warning)?

In that example, imagine "app-svg-team" is written by one team within the company, and wants to create many little components that all cooperate with each other, but can be displayed anywhere on the page the "core team" chooses. This would be a way to let the core team handle laying out individual components from multiple teams. Each team's components could inject services provided by their top-level "team component" even though they may end up in completely unrelated parts of the DOM.

Comment: It should indeed work as moving DOM elements around is by reference so all bindings should keep working fine. However - allowing this ‘free-form’ sounds risky as it might be moved outside app-root or accidentally inside another components DOM element..? It sounds slightly dangerous..

Comment: I would certainly be moved inside another component - that would be part of our plan. :)

So yeah, my question is whether that really is "dangerous", or if Angular is designed in a way that is supposed to support this. To me it seems similar to content projection, where the DOM element is "moved" to be inside a child component. In this case we want to be able to move it to be inside any "cousin" component.

Comment: No idea what the effects of that will be to be honest..

Comment: I don't understand what the advantage of doing it this way is. Avoiding a module import?

Comment: Sort of, yeah. We want to keep our API between teams restricted to component inputs & outputs. Not dependency injection. This policy would ultimately even allow teams that don't even use Angular to contribute.